# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1-\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-\frac{a}{i} )\right]= 1$.

Tags: limits

Let $a \in (0,1)$.

Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(\color{red}{1-}\frac{a}{i}\right)\right] = 1$?

I can show that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1-\prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(1-\frac{a}{i}\right)  \right]  > 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1-\left( 1- \frac{a}{n}\right) ^ n\right] =
1- e^{-a} >
0$$

but how to prove it equals to $1$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE. I have edited to your post to enable latex rendering. Please review it to make sure the question stands as you intended it.

Comment: Huh, is it $\prod \frac{a}{i}$ or $\prod (1-\frac{a}{i})$?

Comment: is there some cite or reference to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $\log(1-x) \leq -x$ for $x \in (0,1)$. So
$$\log \left(\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac a i) \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1 - \frac a i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n - \frac a i \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} - \infty.$$

Comment: beautiful!  thanks